# Yarn NodeManager unexpected SIGTERM

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In an Hadoop 2.6.2 cluster with one ResourceManager (HDFS functional), on Debian 5.10.191-1 (2023-08-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux0 there are 3 DataNodes/NodeManagers.

**Scenario:**
When I launch a basic MapReduce test (QuasiMontecarlo with 1,1)

```bash
/srv/hadoop/bin/yarn jar /srv/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.2.jar pi -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.log.level=DEBUG -Dmapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG -Dmapreduce.reduce.log.level=DEBUG -Dmapred.job.queue.name=myqueue 1 1
```

1. The MRAppMaster starts SUCCESSFULY into a container
2. The YarnChild starts SUCCESSFULY into another container

After the YarnChild, which doing the map task, has SUCCESSFULY terminated and been killed (normal behavior), the NodeManager of the same server receives the signal SIGTERM and shutdown without any other error. Nothing more in DEBUG logs.

**NodeManager logs:**

```
2023-10-08 09:42:38,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 51451 for container-id container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002: 122.2 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.2 GB of 16 GB virtual memory used
2023-10-08 09:42:40,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002
2023-10-08 09:42:40,282 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hadoop   IP=10.0.199.2OPERATION=Stop Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1696758053401_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002
2023-10-08 09:42:40,282 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002 transitioned from RUNNING to KILLING
2023-10-08 09:42:40,283 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002
2023-10-08 09:42:40,301 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2023-10-08 09:42:40,310 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8042
2023-10-08 09:42:40,311 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Exception when trying to cleanup container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002: ExitCodeException exitCode=143: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.killContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.signalContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.cleanupContainer(ContainerLaunch.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher.handle(ContainersLauncher.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher.handle(ContainersLauncher.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2023-10-08 09:42:40,411 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Applications still running : [application_1696758053401_0001]
2023-10-08 09:42:40,414 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Waiting for Applications to be Finished
2023-10-08 09:42:40,414 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1696758053401_0001 transitioned from RUNNING to FINISHING_CONTAINERS_WAIT
2023-10-08 09:42:40,415 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to KILLING
2023-10-08 09:42:40,415 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001
2023-10-08 09:42:40,431 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2023-10-08 09:42:40,438 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Exception when trying to cleanup container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001: ExitCodeException exitCode=143: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.killContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.signalContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.cleanupContainer(ContainerLaunch.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher.handle(ContainersLauncher.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher.handle(ContainersLauncher.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2023-10-08 09:42:40,783 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002 is : 143
2023-10-08 09:42:40,787 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2023-10-08 09:42:40,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /opt/collect_farm/hadoop_data/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002
2023-10-08 09:42:40,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hadoop   OPERATION=Container Finished - Killed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1696758053401_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002
2023-10-08 09:42:40,793 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2023-10-08 09:42:40,793 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Removing container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002 from application application_1696758053401_0001
2023-10-08 09:42:40,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Considering container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002 for log-aggregation
2023-10-08 09:42:40,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1696758053401_0001
2023-10-08 09:42:41,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002
2023-10-08 09:42:41,118 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 51232 for container-id container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001: 275.8 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.6 GB of 16 GB virtual memory used
2023-10-08 09:42:44,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 51232 for container-id container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001: 275.8 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.6 GB of 16 GB virtual memory used
2023-10-08 09:42:44,415 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Done waiting for Applications to be Finished. Still alive: [application_1696758053401_0001]
2023-10-08 09:42:44,415 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 34353
2023-10-08 09:42:44,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 34353
2023-10-08 09:42:44,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService waiting for pending aggregation during exit
2023-10-08 09:42:44,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2023-10-08 09:42:44,418 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Application just finished : application_1696758053401_0001
2023-10-08 09:42:44,420 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.LogAggregationService: Waiting for aggregation to complete for application_1696758053401_0001
2023-10-08 09:42:44,538 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Uploading logs for container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001. Current good log dirs are /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs
2023-10-08 09:42:44,593 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Uploading logs for container container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002. Current good log dirs are /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs
2023-10-08 09:42:44,593 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001/syslog
2023-10-08 09:42:44,594 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001/stdout
2023-10-08 09:42:44,594 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000001/stderr
2023-10-08 09:42:44,595 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002/syslog
2023-10-08 09:42:44,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002/stderr
2023-10-08 09:42:44,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001/container_1696758053401_0001_01_000002/stdout
2023-10-08 09:42:44,774 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /srv/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/userlogs/application_1696758053401_0001
2023-10-08 09:42:44,776 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Can't handle this event at current state
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.InvalidStateTransitonException: Invalid event: APPLICATION_LOG_HANDLING_FINISHED at FINISHING_CONTAINERS_WAIT
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl.handle(ApplicationImpl.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl.handle(ApplicationImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ApplicationEventDispatcher.handle(ContainerManagerImpl.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ApplicationEventDispatcher.handle(ContainerManagerImpl.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2023-10-08 09:42:44,778 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1696758053401_0001 transitioned from FINISHING_CONTAINERS_WAIT to null
2023-10-08 09:42:44,778 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2023-10-08 09:42:44,801 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8040
2023-10-08 09:42:44,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8040
2023-10-08 09:42:44,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2023-10-08 09:42:44,803 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Public cache exiting
2023-10-08 09:42:44,804 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2023-10-08 09:42:44,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2023-10-08 09:42:44,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2023-10-08 09:42:44,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at a-vm-pmzmc-dn01-preprod/10.0.199.23
************************************************************/
```

The ResourceManager just acknowledges the situation and removes the nodemanager from his list 600 seconds after the NodeManagers have stopped and declares each of them as LOST.

The MRAppMaster still running like a ghost process.

**Configuration:**
It's a staging environment copied from a functional prod environment. Same configuration.

This is not a securized hadoop (no Kerberos), it's using the default realm auth.

Administrators have checked the resources and all is ok. I've checked availables resources and all seem ok.

I'm sure that servers see each others.

I have worked on many others similar environments but that's the first time I have such a strange behavior. No error in DEBUG, no Java error, nothing on the OS. I've tried to reinstall several times, changing configurations, resources but I fallback to the same situation each time.

**What I have tried:** 
Increase memory for all: app master, containers, etc.
Run NodeManagers as root (they keep being killed)
Run with one, two, three or four NodeManagers (one per server)

Whatever the reason why a container terminates (success or failure), a few milliseconds later, the NodeManager that hosts the container receives the SIGTERM signal and shutdown.

**UPDATE 1**
We have deployed the same configuration on 3 DataNodes (Suse 5.14) and everything works. The problem seems to be related to the OS.

**UPDATE 2**
The server administrators have check server policies, user rights but the problem remains. The Yarn NodeManager (Hadoop 2.6.2) doesn't seems to work on Debian 5.10.191-1.